# Linux "join" command not working as it should?

Tags: linux, command-line

I am working through the first example here: [Linux Journey](https://linuxjourney.com/lesson/join-split-command)

However, I am not getting the same output after `join file.txt file2.txt`

Instead, I get:

```
 Doehn

 Doene

 Suery
```

I can't figure out what's going on- has the join command syntax changed since the publishing of that website?

Comment: Check your files for carriage returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball says your text files are in DOS format, with carriage-return linefeed (CR LF) line endings. That's why your output looks slightly weird when printed on the console.

To fix it, convert the files to unix format. (You may have a `dos2unix` command; or if you're already using vim, try `:set ff=unix`; or `perl -i -pe 's/\r//' file.txt` will do in a pinch.)

---

The sample files in your link with extra carriage returns are:

**file1.txt**

```
1 John\r
2 Jane\r
3 Mary\r
```

**file2.txt**

```
1 Doe\r
2 Doe\r
3 Sue\r
```

(Using `\r` to represent a carriage return.)

Now when you run `join file1.txt file2.txt`, it will first compare the first field of the first line in each file. This succeeds (`1` on both sides), so `join` outputs the common field, a space, the remaining fields from file 1, another space, then the remaining fields from file 2. So the first line of output is

```
1 John\r Doe\r
```

(`\r` is interpreted as part of the field data).

But wait! `\r` is not a printable character. It has the effect of moving the cursor back to the beginning of the line when printed to a terminal. Using `^` to mark the cursor position, we get the following effect:

```
1
 ^
```

```
1 
  ^
```

```
1 J
   ^
```

```
1 Jo
    ^
```

```
1 Joh
     ^
```

```
1 John
      ^
```

Here we print the first carriage return, moving the cursor back:

```
1 John
^
```

The next output character (a space) overwrites the `1`:

```
  John
 ^
```

```
 DJohn
  ^
```

```
 Doohn
   ^
```

```
 Doehn
    ^
```

Another carriage return, but this one has no visible effect:

```
 Doehn
^
```

And ... done.

The other lines are handled the same way. Each time the carriage return at the end of the last field of file 1 moves the cursor back, so the fields from file 2 overwrite what's already on the screen.

Comment: It worked! Can you explain why having carriage returns would lead to that specific output?